# Finding index of a sub list in a list in python

Tags: python, list, function, recursion

Suppose im given a list `numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and a `sub-list = [4,5,6]` and i want to create a function which can find the starting index of given sub-list in the list.

like,
`numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and
`sub-list = [4,5,6]` should return `3` as the index of sub-list in the list.

can anyone help me to write the function ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: Are they all integers? In a limited range?

Comment: yes they all are integers

Comment: `next(i for i in range(len(numbers)) if numbers[i:i+len(subList)]==subList)`